# Sqlite count data between max and min dates

Tags: sqlite, count

What is the correct way to achieve such a query (not working) ?

```
SELECT Min(mydates_col) as oldest, Max(mydates_col) as newest,
COUNT(oneparticular_column)  FROM  mytable WHERE mydates_col BETWEEN oldest AND newest
```

I understand I can do that using 2 consecutive queries, fetching the min and max dates from the first query, then using thoses numbers to run a second query but I'm convinced there is a much better solution, not found after dozen of tries.

Thx.

Comment: Aren't you retrieving all rows except NULL rows in that case?

Comment: You could therefore do a select count(*) from mytable where mydates_col is not null

Comment: yes, replacing the date range by a NOT NULL condition could be a solution but I'm still afraid of unexpected results. I really wanna focus the count inbetween the min/max date range. Because I need that for other stuffs as well.

Comment: Well, at least in your query, it is impossible to have unexpected results.

Comment: Not with query but with the dB scheme, yes. For example, this is working but not exactly answering my need: : SELECT Min(mydate_col) as oldest, Max(mydate_col) as newest, COUNT(mydata_col)  FROM  mytable
WHERE mydate_col NOT NULL AND mydata_col NOT NULL;

Comment: No as I'm definetly not queries fluent.. :-)

Comment: What's the disadvantage of using two queries by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inner query, not very nice (see my comments) but if you need to:

```
SELECT COUNT(oneparticular_column)  FROM  mytable WHERE mydates_col BETWEEN (SELECT Min(mydates_col) FROM  mytable) AND (SELECT Max(mydates_col) FROM  mytable)
```

Comment: BTW, check that the query gets optimized when running, it might be slow to compute otherwise.

Comment: Great job, exactly matching what I'm strugglying with, many thx :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you also have indexes in your dates to speed up this type of query.